# Is there a way to write a test of a `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` functions?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, sprite-kit, xctest, skphysicscontact

Can I mock `SKPhysicsContact` object to feed into `-(void)didEndContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact` method? Or is there any other technique, that can be leveraged here?

```
class PhysicsTestCase: XCTestCase {

    var physics: GamePhysics!

    ...

    func testCaseOfCollisionsHandling() {

        let contact = SKPhysicsContact()
        contact.bodyA = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10) // Error, 'bodyA' is get-only property

        physics.didEnd(contact) // Physics conforms to `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`
    }

    ...

}

...

// The class that is being tested

class GamePhysics: NSObject, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    // MARK: - SKPhysicsContactDelegate

    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact)  {

        guard let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node, let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node else {
            fatalError("No nodes in colliding bodies")
        }

        switch (nodeB, nodeA) {

        case let (ball as LogicalBall, tile as LogicalTile):
           // Performing some logic

        ...

        }
    }

    func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: You could create a small yet project and initialise your objects on top of each other. `didEndContact` should be called in that situation.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why are you trying to set the physics body? This is not something you would ever do.

Comment: I want to write a set of tests that checks that my `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` works as expected.

Comment: I've never seen an issue with the `SKPhysicsContact`, so not sure that this needs testing. I have written a 'helper' function that, when called, iterates over all nodes in your scene, examines their physics bodies and `contactTest`/`collision` bit masks and reports on which ones collide or notify upon contacting which others. If this sounds useful, it can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sprite-kit/6261/sknode-collision/24162/simple-sprite-kit-project-showing-collisions-contacts-touch-events#t=201705201740011831274 in the `checkPhysics()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm trying to write tests for my class that handles collisions, not that the contactDelegate is called when collision occurs.

Comment: Do you mean tests that handle contacts? No user code is involved in collision handling.

Comment: Yeap, that's what I try to test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, subclassing proposed by Jon Reid in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44101485/482853 is very neat, I didn't managed to make it work in this particular case because of elusive nature of `SKPhysicsContact` class itself.

The way this problem can be solved is to use good old Objective C runtime:

```
func testBallsCollisionIsPassedToHandler() {

    let ballAMock = LogicalBallMock()
    let bodyA = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    bodyA.perform(Selector(("setRepresentedObject:")), with: ballAMock) // So the bodyA.node will return ballAMock

    let ballBMock = LogicalBallMock()
    let bodyB = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    bodyB.perform(Selector(("setRepresentedObject:")), with: ballBMock) // So the bodyB.node will return ballBMock

    let contact = SKPhysicsContact()
    contact.perform(Selector(("setBodyA:")), with: bodyA)
    contact.perform(Selector(("setBodyB:")), with: bodyB)

    physics.didEnd(contact)

    // Assertions ...       

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When we can't change a type because we don't own the API, the solution is to use the legacy code technique Subclass and Override Method:

```
class TestablePhysicsContact: SKPhysicsContact {
    var stubbedBodyA: SKPhysicsBody?

    override var bodyA: SKPhysicsBody {
        return stubbedBodyA!
    }
}
```

To use this in your example test:

```
    func testCaseOfCollisionsHandling() {
        let contact = TestablePhysicsContact()
        contact.stubbedBodyA = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)

        physics.didEnd(contact)

        // assert something
    }
```

For more on this technique, see https://qualitycoding.org/swift-partial-mock/

Comment: Hi Jon, what an honour to get an answer from you : ) I've recently stumbled upon your blog, and got some good ideas from it. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately the solution you've proposed doesn't work. Test crashes because `SKPhysicsContact` is an umbrella class and `contact` turns out to be of a type `PKPhysicsContact` in runtime, even though we initiate it as a `TestablePhysicsContact`.

Comment: But thanks for the idea! It's really neat. I'm so into evading subclassing that didn't even thought of this trick.

Comment: You mean it's a class cluster? Ah too bad.